# software not altered in client authentication

Tags: authentication, cryptography, digital-signature, software-distribution

Is there a way to assure a program running on a remote computer (the client) has not been altered when sending a request to the server?

Let say I have a mobile app which connects to my server requesting some sensible data. Ok I know, the mobile app sends a password, but the password is always stored on the mobile device itself. 
Someone could decompile the app (easily done in JAVA), find the password and modify the program to do whatever he likes and at the same time it would pretend to be my original app.

What I'd like to achieve is to assure that the source code on the client hasn't been modified,therefore that it was actually my original program (unmodified) making the request.

Comment: Yes, with custom tamper-resistant hardware which is crucial for the software to run. Otherwise, no.

Comment: The only code you can trust is the code you keep on your own machines. If you've given it to users for them to install on their machines, you cannot trust that code.

Comment: (Assuming, that is, that you're suitably protecting your own machines. If not, you may not be able to trust the code even there)